How to Use C++ WebAssembly in a React + Vite Project?
I'm trying to integrate a C++ WebAssembly module into my React project using Vite. However, I'm encountering issues with the module not being recognized correctly. Here are the details of my setup:
index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./cpp/triangle.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

App.tsx
const App = () => {
  const area = Module.calculateTriangleArea(10.0, 200.0);
  return <div>{area}</div>;
};

export default App;

wasm.d.ts
declare let Module: {
  calculateTriangleArea: (base: number, height: number) => number;
}

triangle.cpp
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

float calculateTriangleArea(float base, float height) {
    return 0.5f * base * height;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    emscripten::function("calculateTriangleArea", &calculateTriangleArea);
}

Build wasm with emscripten
emcc triangle.cpp -o triangle.js -s WASM=1 -s "EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall', 'cwrap']" -s MODULARIZE=1 -s ENVIRONMENT=web -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 --bind

Issue:
Uncaught TypeError: Module.calculateTriangleArea is not a function
When I try to run the project, I get an error. It seems like the WebAssembly module is not being loaded correctly or not being recognized by the React component.
Questions:

How can I properly load and use the WebAssembly module in my React component?
Is there a specific way to configure Vite to work with WebAssembly modules?
Are there any additional steps or configurations needed to ensure the WebAssembly module is available globally in the React application?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Have you checked with your debugger what Module and Module.calculateTriangleArea are?

@jabaa
Module
ƒ (moduleArg = {})
arguments =null
caller =null
length =0
name =''
prototype ={}
[[FunctionLocation]] =
@ c:\...\...\source\repos\react-app\src\cpp\triangle.js:6
[[Prototype]] =ƒ ()
[[Scopes]] =Scopes[2]


Module.calculateTriangleArea
undefined


Please don't post code in comments. It's not readable. Edit your question and post it there. What's the content of cpp/triangle.js?

I was able to solve the problem by defining an EXPORT_NAME in the emcc command and then using it to access the module.
.... 'EXPORT_NAME="createModule"'

 const wasmModule = await createModule();
 const area = wasmModule.calculateTriangleArea(10.0, 200.0);

